# Firebase Redux state architecture

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm new to firebase. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase).

I started working on an app in redux normally, state was local, dispatching actions, ect. I started hooking it up to firebase, and realized that *once a user signs in*, all of the state values will come from firebase. I have two questions about this.

1. Is firebase an adequate substitute for local state? Don't I lose the benefits of flux state management?
2. I want my users to be able to use the app without signing in, will I need to have a local state management system just for this purpose? If so every action will have to be written to account for both contexts, which seems excessive.

```
const dataFromLocalState
const dataFromFirebase

userSignedIn ? dataFromFirebase.map() : dataFromLocalState.map()
```

and for actions:

```
<button
    onClick={() => userSignedIn ? 
                   firebase.remove(`entries/${id}`) : 
                   dispatch(deleteEntry(id));
    }
>
    Delete
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not recommend to use Firebase for app state management. Expeccialy not for web. If your are using `firestore` you will be charged for each read and write.
2. I the users don't sign in how do you want to separate them on the database? You would need an unique identifier for each user/device.

If you need to store data to Firebase that you also have as local state the best approach would be to use something like a middleware to sync the data from firebase to your local state.

I prsonaly like to use Providers for the Firebase state. Everything that comes from firebase is stored in local state. That way your app can work offline (at least read last statet of the data). You can checkout [here](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/rmw-shell/src/providers/Firebase) how I handle the state.

Also every redux library is a good solution. The reason we moved to Provisers is that in large apps they get laggy because of the huge amount of data that goes trough redux.